# How to decode this nested repeated json object to dataframe

Tags: r, json, jsonlite

I am trying to decode a repeated json object as data frame in R. I am able to decode the first part but the object is repeating while showing information for next column ( It would be best if you see the code)

Expected:

[image]

The dataset

```
structure(list(X__1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), country = c(3, 3, 3, 
3, 3), message = c("<p>Con la tua firma, ripartiamo insieme. <br> In sede di dichiarazione dei redditi dona il <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">2x1000</span></span></a> al <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">PD</span></span></a>, scrivi <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">M20</span></span></a>.<br> A te non costa nulla, insieme saremo piÃ¹ liberi.</p>", 
"<p>Con la tua firma, ripartiamo insieme</p>", "<p>Lâ\200\231apprendimento permanente Ã¨ la piÃ¹ grande possibilitÃ  per garantire un lavoro stabile durante la tua carriera. Ã\210 un tuo diritto formarti per il tuo (prossimo) lavoro. Noi vogliamo una garanzia per le competenze europea. Vogliamo un pilastro europeo dei diritti sociali. Vogliamo anche un piano europeo di azione sociale. <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">SocialSummit17</span></span></a> <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">SocialEurope</span></span></a> <a class=\"_58cn\"><span class=\"_5afx\"><span class=\"_58cl _5afz\">#</span><span class=\"_58cm\">Gothenburg</span></span></a></p>", 
"<p>Che brutta giornata per lâ\200\231Italia e per la Democrazia.<br> Era tutto pronto, anche io ero pronto a occuparmi di immigrazione e sicurezza, ma niente, qualcuno oggi ha detto NO.<br> Il governo del cambiamento non poteva nascere, i Signori dello Spread e delle banche, i ministri di Berlino, di Parigi e di Bruxelles non erano dâ\200\231accordo.<br> Rabbia? Tanta. Paura? Zero.<br> Cambieremo questo Paese, insieme.<span class=\"text_exposed_hide\">...</span><span class=\"text_exposed_show\"><br> Io non mollo Amici, conto su di Voi.<br> Prima gli italiani!</span></p>", 
"<div class=\"mbs _5pbx\" id=\"js_5oc\">Cambiamo insieme la Basilicata x un futuro migliore! Segui il nostro lavoro giornoxgiorno!</div>"
), created_at = structure(c(1527751501, 1526307860, 1510831668, 
1527504155, 1526925698), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    updated_at = structure(c(1528033793, 1526892761, 1510831798, 
    1527763853, 1528640033), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    lang = c("it-IT", "it-IT", "it-IT", "it-IT", "it-IT"), political_probability = c(0.996111675473273, 
    0.898237740210695, 0.78140195632652, 0.996097443958498, 0.780792285415908
    ), targets = c("{\"target\": \"Age\", \"segment\": \"compresa tra 35 e 64 anni \"}", 
    "{\"target\": \"Age\", \"segment\": \"compresa tra 25 e 64 anni \"}", 
    NA, "{\"target\": \"Age\", \"segment\": \"pari o superiore a 13 anni \"}", 
    "{\"target\": \"Age\", \"segment\": \"18 and older\"}, {\"target\": \"Region\", \"segment\": \"Basilicata\"}"
    ), advertiser = c("Partito Democratico", "Partito Democratico", 
    "Partito del Socialismo Europeo", "Matteo Salvini", "Gianni Rosa"
    ), id = c(3228, 3229, 3230, 3231, 3232)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

My try

I tried to read the file then  tried to decode it using jsonlite package

```
doc <-read_excel("italy.xlsx")
doc[doc$targets == "NA"] <- NA

flatten_json <- . %>% 
  str_c(., collapse = ",") %>% 
   str_c("[", ., "]") %>% 
  # str_c("{", ., "}") %>% 
   fromJSON(flatten = T)


parse <- . %>% 
  bind_cols(flatten_json(.$targets))

doc <- parse(doc)
```

The result I am getting is working on for row 1 & 2 because they dont have nested structure, it fails for "NA" & blank rows & also for nested structure like row 5

Comment: What output are you expecting in row 5?

Comment: The fifth one isn't nested, it's just two nodes with a comma between them. Wrap it in `[...]` maybe.

Comment: @anotherfred: Row 5 output is given in image attached

Comment: @alistaire: Not sure how to do make it work, could you help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep the data associated with the current rows, you'll need to iterate `fromJSON` across `targets`. You'll need to deliberately skip the `NA` value, though (putting in a placeholder that will expand nicely), and wrap everything in `[...]`, because the fifth observation is poorly formed JSON.

Afterwards, you'll need some munging to get it into the correct form. `tidyr::unnest` will expand the list column, and `tidyr::spread` will reshape the data to wide form.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>% 
    mutate(targets = map(targets, ~if (is.na(.x)) {    # iterate, create list column
            tibble(target = 'Age')    # what to return for NAs
        } else {
            jsonlite::fromJSON(paste0('[', .x, ']'))    # parse fixed JSON
        })) %>% 
    unnest() %>%     # expand list column
    spread(target, segment)    # reshape from long to wide form

df2
#> # A tibble: 5 x 11
#>    X__1 country message created_at          updated_at          lang 
#>   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>
#> 1     1       3 "<p>Co… 2018-05-31 07:25:01 2018-06-03 13:49:53 it-IT
#> 2     2       3 <p>Con… 2018-05-14 14:24:20 2018-05-21 08:52:41 it-IT
#> 3     3       3 "<p>L\… 2017-11-16 11:27:48 2017-11-16 11:29:58 it-IT
#> 4     4       3 "<p>Ch… 2018-05-28 10:42:35 2018-05-31 10:50:53 it-IT
#> 5     5       3 "<div … 2018-05-21 18:01:38 2018-06-10 14:13:53 it-IT
#> # … with 5 more variables: political_probability <dbl>, advertiser <chr>,
#> #   id <dbl>, Age <chr>, Region <chr>

df2 %>% select(id, Age, Region)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 3
#>      id Age                           Region    
#>   <dbl> <chr>                         <chr>     
#> 1  3228 "compresa tra 35 e 64 anni "  <NA>      
#> 2  3229 "compresa tra 25 e 64 anni "  <NA>      
#> 3  3230 <NA>                          <NA>      
#> 4  3231 "pari o superiore a 13 anni " <NA>      
#> 5  3232 18 and older                  Basilicata
```

Comment: This almost works perfectly I just have doubt actually my data has a "[" this symbol to the start of all targets values & "]" at the end. How do I run above with that 
I get this error on that Error: Each column must either be a list of vectors or a list of data frames [targets]

Comment: Yeah, the right question is how you ended up with this structure in the first place, because the ideal time to take care of this is when reading in the JSON as a whole. You're ending up with malformed JSON, which is going to create as many problems as ways it is messed up, so you can track them all back, but it may be better to start fixing the problem earlier.